# Laravel Lumen Logging not working on production

Tags: php, laravel, logging, lumen

I have a small project on Laravel/Lumen where I use logging messages like this

```
Log::info('User failed to login.', 
    ['Env token' => $this->envToken, 'Request token' =>$request->header('Authorization')]);
```

I can check my log in `storage/logs/lumen.log` just fine. The problem is when I push it to my vps where the log stops working. In there I ran `composer install --no-dev` to install the production dependencies only.

Is there a required dev dependency for logging or it can be something else??

More info:
Vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/logging.php (I haven't change it, so it's by default)

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Log Channel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option defines the default log channel that gets used when writing
| messages to the logs. The name specified in this option should match
| one of the channels defined in the "channels" configuration array.
|
*/

'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log channels for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Drivers: "single", "daily", "slack", "syslog",
|                    "errorlog", "custom", "stack"
|
*/

'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/lumen.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/lumen.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 7,
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Lumen Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'critical',
    ],

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'errorlog' => [
        'driver' => 'errorlog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
],

];
```

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=stuffkey
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC    

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=stuffdb
DB_USERNAME=stuffuser
DB_PASSWORD=stuffkey

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

RESTTOKEN=blablablabla
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/logging.php` file along with your `env` variables related to logging as they are in your VPS environment?

Comment: In laravel lumen there's not config/logging.php like in laravel. But there is a config/logging.php on Vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/logging.php